# Image conversion, numpy error "only integer scalar arrays can be converted to a scalar index"

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, matplotlib, image-processing

I want to convert a grayscale image to a binary representation (black and white representation). I did this by using nested for loops but I got the error as mentioned in the title. Are there any tips and tricks to bypass this error.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fname = 'nao_bw.jpg'
img = plt.imread('/Users/anil/Desktop/nao_bw.jpg')
imgplot = plt.imshow(img)
img_as_np = np.asarray(img)
for i in range(img_as_np):
    for j in range(img_as_np):
        if img_as_np[i,j]< 100 and img[i,j]>150:
            img_as_np[i,j] = 0
        else:
            img_as_np[i,j] = 255
plt.show()
```

Comment: Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation, as suggested when you created this account.  [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) applies here.  We cannot effectively help you until you post your MCVE code and accurately describe the problem.
We should be able to paste your posted code into a text file and reproduce the problem you described.  In particular, supply the full error message and the input needed to reproduce it.

Answer (score 1):

That's not an error from numpy, that error comes when you try to do `range(img_as_np)`. You are trying to create a range object from a numpy array which makes no sense. It's like if you wrote `range(np.array([[1,2],[3,4]]))`, what do you want the range function to do? I'm guessing you want `range(len(img_as_np))` and you have a square image. If the image is not square, then you should have:

```
    for i in range(img_as_np.shape[0]):
        for j in range(img_as_np.shape[1]):
            ...
```